# Matplotlib version does not match Anaconda version

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

I've installed the Anaconda2-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and when I run `conda list` I see that the matplotlib version should be 2.1.2. But when I run python I get that the version is 2.0.2 :

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'2.0.2'
```

Why the python package does point on the matplotlib version from Anaconda?

Comment: Do you have several environments installed? Or do you have another python version outside of anaconda installed?

Comment: I too think it is important to mention if you are working with virtual environments. Did you `source activate` your virtual environment before running `python`? Did you `conda install matplotlib` from your virtual environment?